# Microsoft Bot Framework - How to change presentation message

Tags: bots, botframework

I'm working on a project based on Microsoft BotFramework.
I would to change the Bot description message like:

*Hi! I'm xxxx. Say "hi" if you'd like to chat*

Would be also a great result at least to be able to localize the description.

Thanks,

Sebastiano

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the relevant parts of the code you have tried.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no code I tried as I don't know how to modify it at all. 
I followed standard procedure as explained into samples and docs. Everything works, simply I don't know where are options to modify to do what I explained.

Comment: If you are using a Form Dialog, then there is a Message method on the FormBuilder. What kind of Bot are you looking to create?

Comment: Hi Andy,
I'm not using FormFlow but IDialog based Bot, better a LuisDialog based bot.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add your message in block **(message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)**

```
private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
    {
        if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
        {
            // Implement user deletion here
            // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            // Not available in all channels
            string replyMessage = "Hi, <Custom Message>";
            return message.CreateReply(replyMessage);
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle add/remove from contact lists
            // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
        {
            // Handle knowing that the user is typing
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
        {
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature which is in our backlog to implement.

Comment: Any updates regarding this? If we can change the starting message of the bot, it will solve some of our UI/UX problems.